# How to get firebase functions from firebase server - i don't have it locally

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

A time ago i've created functions (API) on my firebase, i would like to add more but I don't have the files locally, neither on github.
How can I get them from the firebase server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the source of the scripts from Google Cloud Functions:
https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/list

- You can then access each function independently here.
  [image: Image of Cloud Functions]

This will take you to a window with several tabs.

- Click the **SOURCE** tab and then **Download Zip**
  [image: Details of Cloud Function]

**Depending on your build, it may be missing some components and modules but it is a way to recover them in a practical manor.*